# Print all lines in a file not beginning with hash and also filter by a specific column

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I've got a tab separated file with header lines beginning with `#`. I want to trim all the header lines and also the lines where column `#2` does not begin with `0/0`.

I've got the first logic (removing the header lines) right but when I add the second logic (which I'm not sure if it is the right way to do) with an `AND` nothing gets returned.

```
awk -F$'\t' '/^[^#]/ && $2 !~ /^0\\/0/ {print;}' test.txt
```

**Inputfile**

```
#meta1
#meta2
10  0/2:1/2
10  0/0:5/5
10  2/6:0/0
```

**Outputfile**

```
10  0/2:1/2
10  2/6:0/0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed Input_file so adding solution as per Ed sir's suggestions in comments too.

```
awk '!(/^#/ || $2~/^0\/0/)'  Input_file
```

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk '!/^#meta/ && $2!="0/0"'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '!/^#/ && $2!="0/0"'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '!(/^#/ || $2=="0/0")'  Input_file
```

SET `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` in case your Input_file is TAB separated and you need `OFS` output as `\t` TAB too.